# Does this crack in a battery terminal post indicate that the battery should be replaced?

Tags: battery

Mechanics at the local garage have insisted it's "no problem yet", but people here in Sierra Leone have different standards to me when it comes to car safety...

This is a pic of the positive terminal post on my car battery:

[image]

Looks to me like a crack, going from near the bottom at the front just left of centre, across the top in a reverse `c` shape, then down the other side. Whatever's under that cracked metal casing is visible through the crack.

It's hard (but not impossible) to attach the connector terminal - it feels like the post is maybe 0.5mm too wide and it takes some pushing to get it on.

I know any sort of crack to the battery casing is serious - but is something like this on a terminal post merely cosmetic, or is it terminal? (pun intended)

The battery works and can hold a charge, but discharges when not in use faster than I might expect.

Comment: It's made of soft lead so they will get a deformed look like that from getting a clamp tightened down on them.  Looks OK.

Comment: As said ... this is not an issue. It looks like someone put a hard wire over the top of the terminal then put the clamp down over it. This would mean it's not a crack, just a deformation. I also wanted to say, thank you so much for the picture ... in this case it is worth about a billion words (not just the customary 1,000 :D)

Comment: Depending on latitude and usage,modern batteries only last 2-5 years.  Get as much use out of it as you can as-is.  When it starts to fail, then replace it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They are right. Its not a problem yet. There are no signs that battery fluid is escaping through the post. Keep an eye on it, though. :)